# CSS Background Image Specific Rule for iPad and iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site & the background image isn't displayed correctly on iPhone & iPad, could someone please direct me as to what I should place in my CSS stylesheet to have the iPhone & iPad exclude the background image entirely?

Your help is much appreciated.

**EDIT** I've added this to my stylesheet.css, but it still isn't working correctly.

```
    /* iphone 5 */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    background-image: none; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


/* iphone 2-4 */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { 
    background-image: none; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* ipad mini */

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  {
    background-image: none; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* ipad 1-2 */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1){
    background-image: none; 
    background-color: #ffffff;

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the bit of code that affects the problem, rather than everything.

Comment: I think the question shouldn't be "how to exclude iOS" but "how to fix for iOS". If you want to exclude something for iOS it is quite easy there are lots of libraries on the web for detecting this, if you want to fix this please post your problem on a jsfiddle-like.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a separate stylesheet and add it if the user agent string matches an iPhone or iPad.

```
IS_IPAD = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
IS_IPHONE = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null);
if (IS_IPAD) {
    IS_IPHONE = false;
}
```

Comment: Good approach, but let's try to fix the iOS problem instead of removing some features.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Javascript

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
      document.getElementById('myDiv').style.background = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to remove the background image but from which html element? on your media queries you have this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    background-image: none; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

but you are not specifying what background image from which html element should be remove.
let said that you are trying to remove the background image from the body. then you could do this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    body{
        background-image: none; 
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
}
```

as an option you could change the regular background image that you're using and change its size so it works on iphone, then you could call that image using the media queries for iphone.